# How to conditionally show a partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I dynamically show a partial view in Rails?

I'm trying something like this:

```
def showdata(summary)
    blah = 'test'
    if summary
        partial('partial1', locals: { blah })
    else
        partial('partial2', locals: { blah })
    end
```

I'm very new to rails :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use render ([this is the reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)), and for your code here is the sample

```
def showdata(summary)
    blah = 'test'
    if summary
        render('partial1', locals: { blah })
    else
        render('partial2', locals: { blah })
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible:

```
render partial: "partial1", locals: { blah } if summary
render partial: "partial2", locals: { blah } if !summary
```

or using the ternary operator

```
render partial: summary? "partial1" : "partial2", locals: { blah }
```